# Why is it flickering Object Object in my component when it's rendered for the first time, (Angular)

Tags: angular, forms, httprequest, angular-reactive-forms

I'm filling a form from a Http request, but when the form is rendered for the first time it shows [object object]in the input for a few milliseconds and then it shows the value of the input.

this is what I got in my .ts file:

```
this.customerInitialSvc.getInitialData().subscribe((data: InitialData) => {
      const { Data } = data;
      this.datosInicialesForm.patchValue({
        primerNombre: Data['firstName'],
        segundoNombre: Data['secondName'],
        primerApellido: Data['firstSurname'],
        segundoApellido: Data['secondSurname'],
        fechaDeNacimiento: this.formatDate(new Date()),
        documentoIdentidad: Data['identification'],
        teléfono: Data['phoneNumber'],
      });

and this is my html file:

<form
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)"
    fxLayout="column stretch"
    fxLayout.lt-md="column"
    fxLayoutGap="5px"
    fxFlex.lt-md="100"
    [formGroup]="datosInicialesForm"
  >
    <div
      fxLayout="row wrap"
      fxLayout.lt-lg="column"
      fxFlexAlign="center"
      fxLayoutGap.gt-sm="50px"
      fxLayoutGap.lt-md="20px"
      fxFlex.lt-md="90"
    >
      <div class="input-field">
        <label>Primer Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="primerNombre" />
      </div>

      <div class="input-field">
        <label>Segundo Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="segundoNombre" />
      </div>

      <div class="input-field">
        <label>Primer Apellido:</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="primerApellido" />
      </div>
    </div>
.........
```

I hope someone can help me.

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

It's because the form controls have no value until your http request returns and fills them in. You could either set default values to your form controls, or I think adding placeholders on the fields would hide it too.

```
<div class="input-field">
        <label>Primer Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder='Primer Nombre' formControlName="primerNombre" />
      </div>

      <div class="input-field">
        <label>Segundo Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder='Segundo Nombre' formControlName="segundoNombre" />
      </div>

      <div class="input-field">
        <label>Primer Apellido:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder='Primer Apellido' formControlName="primerApellido" />
      </div>
    </div>
```